# Does a for loop empty a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How can I get the items of the list as an output in the 2nd & 3rd part? (Every time I want to print them, they just print the letters from an item from the list.)

```
foods = ["pizza", "burger", "popcorn", "cannoli", "noodles"]
print("The foods I like are:\n")
for foods in foods[:3]:
    print(foods.title())
#2nd
print("The foods my friend likes are:\n")
for foods in foods[1:4]:
    print(foods.title())
#3rd
print("The food SHE likes are:\n")
for foods in foods[:]:
    print(foods.title())
```

Comment: When you do for foods in foods[:3], you reassign the value of foods. Try it this way. for food in foods[:3]: print(food.title())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite `foods` in each iteration. Please try this:

```
foods = ["pizza", "burger", "popcorn", "cannoli", "noodles"]
#2nd
print("The foods my friend likes are:\n")
for f in foods[1:4]:
    print(f.title())
#3rd
print("The food SHE likes are:\n")
for f in foods[:]:
    print(f.title())
```